# Getting plain JavaScript files to work with the TypeScript module system

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, requirejs, bundling-and-minification

I am using Visual Studio to create a ASP.NET Core 2.2 web app using TypeScript, and I have included the `two.js` library along with the `two.d.js` (TypeScript declaration file) from the npm package I've found online.

The problem is that I don't understand how to get modules working (perhaps it's not related to `two.js` but using plain JavaScript with modules in general).

`two.js` file uses JSDoc, but doesn't have any exports as far as I can see.

So my project has these files ([two.d.js](https://pastebin.com/TdpeNV31), [two.js](https://pastebin.com/2Qq8vg3C) and [site.ts](https://pastebin.com/dGXHne2x)):

```
+ js
  - two.d.js
  - two.js
  - site.ts
  - something.ts
```

And `site.js` file is importing `two.js` and `something.ts` at the beginning:

```
// this uses the 'two.d.js' file and I get intellisense
import { Two } from "./two";

// this is some .ts file
import { Something } from "./something";

// create the Two.js instance
let placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');

// this line is what I want to get running
let twojs = new Two({ width: 1900, height: 885 }).appendTo(placeholder);
```

However, when `site.ts` gets compiled, any modules option I try fail in the browser:

1. **"None"** (i.e. no module system): Fails with `exports` is not defined in the first line of the compiled `site.js` file:

   ```
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
   ```
2. **ES2015** native module system: Fails with "404 not found" for `./something` and `./two`.
    TypeScript compiler doesn't append the `.js` extension to the native browser `import` statement, so these files cannot be loaded. However if I add the extension in TypeScript then I get a compile error.
3. **AMD/RequireJS**: I get the "`Two` is not a constructor" exception. 
    Code gets compiled to this and I can see all `.js` files loaded correctly, however I guess the problem is that `two.js` doesn't export anything natively:

   ```
   define(["require", "exports", "./something", "./two"], function (require, exports, something, two_1) {

       "use strict";
       Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
       let placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');

       // Two is not a constructor
       let twojs = new two_1.Two({ width: 1900, height: 885 }).appendTo(placeholder);

   });
   ```

Ideally, I would like to have a single bundled .js file per each page to reduce module loader server roundtrips, but I am open to other options.

Answer (score 2):

The `two.js` is not exporting anything, it's exposing `Two` as a global variable, thus the `two.d.ts` is bluntly WRONG at type-annotating the module (in fact `two.js` doesn't qualify as a "module"). You need to correct it first.

1. You need to replace all top-level `export` keyword with `declare` keyword in `two.d.ts`. That'll tell TS `two.js` is NOT a module and instead it exposes some global variables.
2. `site.ts` can now directly refer to `Two` the global variable, no more `import` needed. As a good practice, it's advised to place a triple slash directive at the top of this file to show the dependency relationship. This will also put the content of `two.js` before `site.js` when bundled (see next step).

```
/// <reference path="./two.js" />

let twojs = new Two({ width: 1900, height: 885 }).appendTo(placeholder);
```

3. config **tsconfig.json** as following. Run `tsc` in command line, it will compile and bundle all your `.js` and `.ts` file into one single file. You might need to config "include" (or "files") field to cover all related resource, (e.g. two.js, two.d.ts) according to your project's file structure. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

```
{
    "include": [...],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "outFile": "bundle.js",
        "allowJs": true  // to include `two.js` into the bundle
    }
}
```

4. include your scripts in HTML using RequireJS.

```
<script data-main="scripts/bundle" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```